# Twig custom text field not displaying - syntax wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

Is anyone here familiar with Twig? The Wordpress theme Realia is supposed to display a custom text field when the price field is left empty. But it doesn't. Here is the code that I think is responsible.

```html
<div class="property span9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image span3">
            <div class="content">
                <a href="{{ wp.get_permalink(property.ID) }}"></a>
                {% if wp.get_the_post_thumbnail(property.ID) %}
                    <img src="{{ wp.aq_resize(wp.wp_get_attachment_url(wp.get_post_thumbnail_id(property.ID), 'full'), 270, 200, 'true') }}" alt="{{ property.post_title }}">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="{{ wp.get_template_directory_uri() }}/assets/img/property-tmp-small.png" alt="{{ property.post_title }}">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.image -->

        <div class="body span6">
            <div class="title-price row">
                <div class="title span4">
                    <h2><a href="{{ wp.get_permalink(property.ID) }}">{{ property.post_title }}</a></h2>
                </div>
                <!-- /.title -->

                <div class="price">
                    {% if wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_custom_text').0 %}
                        {{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_custom_text').0 }}
                    {% else %}

                    {{ wp.aviators_price_format(property.meta._property_price.0) }}{% if property.meta._property_price_suffix.0 %}
                        <span class="suffix">{{ property.meta._property_price_suffix.0 }}</span>{% endif %}</div>

                    {% endif %}
                <!-- /.price -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.title -->

            <div class="location">{{ property.location.0.name }}</div>
            <!-- /.location -->

            <div class="body">
                {{ wp.aviators_core_get_post_teaser(property.ID) }}
            </div>
            <!-- /.body -->

            <div class="info clearfix">
                {% if property.meta._property_area.0 %}
                    <div class="area">
                        <span class="key">{{ wp.__('Area', 'aviators') }}:</span><!-- /.key -->
                        <span class="value">{{ property.meta._property_area.0 }}{{ wp.aviators_settings_get_value('properties', 'units', 'area')|raw }}</span><!-- /.value -->
                    </div><!-- /.area -->
                {% endif %}

                {% if property.meta._property_bedrooms.0 %}
                    <div class="bedrooms" title="{{ wp.__('Bedrooms', 'aviators') }}">
                        <div class="content">{{ property.meta._property_bedrooms.0 }}</div>
                    </div><!-- /.bedrooms -->
                {% endif %}

                {% if property.meta._property_bathrooms.0 %}
                    <div class="bathrooms" title="{{ wp.__('Bathrooms', 'aviators') }}">
                        <div class="content">{{ property.meta._property_bathrooms.0 }}</div>
                    </div><!-- /.bathrooms -->
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <!-- /.info -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.property -->
```

Comment: I assume you're talking about the line with `{% if property.meta._property_price_suffix.0 %}`?  You may want to reduce your question to include only the relevant code. You say when the price field is empty, but is it empty or is it zero?  The documentation at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html is useful

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{% if property.meta._property_price_suffix == false %}
```

The table at the end of the documentation at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html is useful.